# How to get data through JSON in a particular format

Tags: java, json, servlets, jquery, gson

Following is the code snippet which is used to get the online roster from gtalk

```
                     if (status == true) {
         Roster roster =connection.getRoster(); 
         Collection<RosterEntry> entries =roster.getEntries(); 
         System.out.println(roster.getEntryCount()); 
         int count1 = 0; 
         int count2 = 0; 
         for(RosterEntry r:entries)
          { 
          Presence presence = roster.getPresence(r.getUser());
          if(presence.getType() == Presence.Type.unavailable)
          {
         // System.out.println(user + "is offline");
          count1++; 
          } 
          else
          { 
              String rosterNamesJson = new Gson().toJson(r.getName()); 
              String rosterUserJson =new Gson().toJson(r.getUser());
              response.setContentType("application/json");
              response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
              //array of 2 elements
             String  rosterInfoJson=response.getWriter().write("rosterNamesJson"+"rosterUserJson"]);
              response.sendRedirect("Roster.jsp");
              //System.out.println(name+user + "is online"); 
              count2++;
    }
          }
}
```

Now in my jsp page I want to populate the roster as name and his jid i.e xoxoxo:xoxoxo@gmail.com 
jjj:jjj@gmail.com and so on. How do I achieve this?

Should I construct Json element i.e

```
users
 {
   name:
   jid:
  }
```

and then write function in my JSP page to access the data?

The function I have is

```
     $(function() {
        $.getJSON('xxxServlet', function(rosterInfoJson) {
            var $ul = $('<ul>').appendTo($('#roster'));
            $.each(rosterInfoJson, function(index, rosterEntry) {
                $('<li>').text(rosterEntry.user).appendTo($ul);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

yes. you should construct your JSON as

```
 users
  {
   name:
   jid:
  }
```

You may want to define a Java class mapping the JSON.

```
public class MyUser{
  public String name;
  public String jid;
  public MyUser(String name, String jid){
    this.name=name;
    this.jid=jid;
  }
}
```

And then, just append all the online uses to a List or something

```
ArrayList<MyUser> mul = new ArrayList<MyUser>();
if (status == true) {
 ...
 ...
 for(RosterEntry r:entries) { 
  if(...){
         ... 
  } 
  else
  { 
    mul.add(new MyUser(r.getName(),r.getUser());
    count2++; 
  }
 }

response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJSON(mul));
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
response.sendRedirect("Roster.jsp");
```

In your JavaScript

```
...
$('<li>').text(rosterEntry.name +":"+rosterEntry.jid).appendTo($ul);
...
```

Comment: @Nishanth-Why would I need a java class??I am not able to understand the mapping..

Comment: @xoxoxo well, `new Gson().toJson("Some String")` gives `"Some String"`. You need to package as a Java Object because you wanted to create a JSON object that is exact replica of it. You may just use a HashMap as well, if you do not want to use Object. `HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>(); hm.put("name", r.getName()); hm.put("jid", r.getUser()); mul.add(hm);` this will do the same thing.